# Best way to calculate mean from database with too many outliers (0s) in price variable

Tags: sql, r, statistics, dbplyr

At my job, I was asked to calculate the mean for prices in specific articles from the company's database. Issue is that many values in database are 0, so simply calculating the mean may pull the results down because of the 0s. My question has two dimensions.

First: the approach from a data analyst perspective. Should I trim the mean in R, or use standard deviation for correcting outliers?

Second: How can I use that approach and apply it at my company's database?. Either with SQL or R in dbplyr code.

The idea is trying to find the most representative price for every object.

Down here a repr-ex showing the most similitar distribution with the diamonds dataset. Showing high concentration at 0, and following a similar distribution after.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(dbplyr)
library(DBI)
library(odbc)
library(datasets)
library(ggplot2)


#### Original dataset

dbWriteTable(conn = prueba,
             name = 'reprex_diamonds',
             value = diamonds)

tbl(prueba,'reprex_diamonds') %>% 
  ggplot() + geom_density(aes(carat))


### In this case I have several concentrations of values. 
### If for example I have a database with prices with many values being 0, 
### what options can I do to create a more robust or better mean value with SQL or Dbplyr for an analysis.
### In this case if I calculate the mean without doing anything, the 0s are pulling my mean down.


##### This is the result I would want. 
mtcars %>% ggplot() + geom_density(aes(mpg))
```

Perhaps not the distribution since it wouldnt be real, bu a cleanear, more representative value.
I would like to know, both the codes in SQL or Dbplyr to extract the data and the logic for  data analysis. Wheter is with trim(), filtering data from 1 or 2 standard deviations. What would be recommended?

Comment: try median and trimmed means.

Comment: You need to decide the purpose for the calculation. That should inform the decision whether to exclude the zero values. It's easy to exclude zero values from a vector: `vec[vec>0]`

Comment: Are you hoping for a SQL (language) solution, or is the only reason you have that tag because you are connecting to a database? (If the latter, please remove the [tag:sql] tag, it is not helpful, stick with [tag:dbplyr] and/or [tag:dplyr].)

Comment: How are you getting a high concentration at zero using `reprex_diamonds`? The `min(ggplot2::diamonds$carat)` is 0.2. As to your questions: (1) A `0` can be meaningful or clearly an error. Regardless, try pulling all of it, counting how many zeroes you have, plot densities without zeroes but include the count/percentage of zeroes on the plot ("full disclosure"). That's one option. (2) It's stil `dplyr`, so `tbl(..) %>% collect()` should pull it. I don't see where the question here is.

Answer (score 1):

First: If we can assume the price equal to zero is meaningless for your company, the correct approach is to exclude the zeros to calculate the mean. If the zeros are important, the best approach is to calculate the mean with and without the zeros and evaluate both results. Besides the zero problems, if your data has an asymmetrical or skewed distribution, you may consider using other measures of central tendencies such as median or mode.
To give a more precise answer, it would be necessary to know more about your company's objective with these statistics and what the zeros represent in your database.

Second: In R you can just filter out the while calculating the mean, as in the example code below.

```
# Filtering out the zeros to calculate the mean of the variable "z" from the 'diamonds' dataset    
mean(diamonds[!diamonds$z==0,]$z)
```

Please let me know if this helps you.

Answer (score 0):

You've tagged this question dbplyr, so I'm assuming you are looking for a database-friendly solution. dbplyr will translate many standard dplyr commands hence we need to limit ourselves primarily to these.

You can compute means excluding zeros using something like:

```r
remote_table = tbl(db_connection,'reprex_diamonds')

remote_means = remote_table %>%
  filter(price != 0) %>%
  summarise(avg = mean(price))
```

To test the dbplyr translation you can use `show_query(remote_means)`. This will display the code that will be executed in the database. Note that at this point everything is still occurring in the database. To pull the database results into local R memory you can use `local_means = collect(remote_means)`.

Your example code includes a plot not a mean calculation. If you are wanting to produce plots, then you will need to pull the data from SQL into R. Best practice would be to pull as little data as necessary. Perhaps something like this:

```r
remote_prices = remote_table %>%
  filter(price != 0) %>%
  select(price)

local_prices = collect(remote_prices)

ggplot(local_prices) + geom_density(aes(price))
```

This will filter the data in SQL and only pull into R the prices you need for your plot. The plot is then made in R. The plot can not be made in SQL as ggplot commands do not exist in SQL.